# trying to get HTML Radio to trigger a function to show image

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, radio-button

im trying to get this to work to show an image when a radial is clicked and remove it when the other is selected

```
function showprediction()
{
    var Radio= document.getElementByName("tf");
    if(type[0] == true)
    {
        var img = document.create('img');
        img.src= "images/FlatPhoto.jpg";
        document.getElementById('body').appendChild(img);  
    }
    else if(type[1] == true)
    {
        var img = document.create('img');
        img.src= "images/RoundPhoto.jpg";
        document.getElementById('body').appendChild(img);  
    }
}'''
```

Comment: Can you please help me with your html code .. also which image has to be shown when ? and when it has to be removed ?

Comment: this is the relevant code for HTML                  ```<label>True</label>
                <input type="radio" id="true" name="tf" value="true">
                <label>False</label>
                <input type="radio" id="false" name="tf" value="false">
                <img src="images/FlatPhoto.jpg" name="flat"/>
                <img src="images/Roundphoto.jpg" name="round"/>```

Comment: also it is rather hidden so small mistake their

Comment: You mentioned that you have to remove the element but I don't see it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```js
    let imgs = document.querySelector('#imgs')
    let create_img
    imgs.addEventListener('change', e =>{
      if(create_img)
        create_img.remove()
      create_img = document.createElement('img')
      create_img.setAttribute('src', e.target.value)
      document.body.appendChild(create_img)
    })
```

```html
<div id="imgs">
      Image 1 <input type="radio" value="https://img.ibxk.com.br/2020/01/30/30021141299110.jpg?w=1120&h=420&mode=crop&scale=both" name="img">
      Image 2 <input type="radio" value="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/11/21/17/02/lion-66898_960_720.jpg" name="img">
</div>
```

Here I created a div that will contain the inputs and from that div it is checked if one of these inputs was clicked through the 'change' event, if this occurs it will add the image using the input value

Comment: hey does this work with saved images and should I add this to document ready

Comment: Just put the saved image directory in value